# How to Add Multiple Locations in Apple Bussiness Manager Account for Custom Apps

Tags: ios, iphone

I need Help to Add Multiple Locations to the **Apple business manager** console. We have 2 Administration accounts and in Location Sections only USA Location. but we also Need to Add Multiple Countries or Global App Available under Custom apps.so Any user from Anywhere Redeem Codes Provided from ABM Custom Apps. I also attached the screenshot.
[image]
When I try to add **Locations** from  **( + )** sections I got only USA States List not any country Selection.

First I have generated code for custom apps.
I got a code list with App URLs in Sheet.
then I try to install it on my iPhone I got an Error. **(This code is only valid for customers of the united states.)**